How to set Options in UI component based on the response from a AJAX request?
<dynamicRows name="dynamic_rows">
            <settings>
                <addButtonLabel translate="true">Add Record</addButtonLabel>
                <dndConfig>
                <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                <param name="draggableElementClass" xsi:type="string">_dragged</param>
                <param name="tableClass" xsi:type="string">table.admin__dynamic-rows</param>
                </dndConfig>
                <additionalClasses>
                    <class name="admin__field-wide">true</class>
                </additionalClasses>
                <componentType>dynamicRows</componentType>
                <dataScope>dynamic_rows</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="field_1" formElement="input">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="fit" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                    <settings>
                        <validation>
                            <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                        </validation>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <label translate="true">In Database</label>
                    </settings>
                </field>
                <actionDelete template="Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/cells/action-delete">
                <settings>
                    <additionalClasses>
                        <class name="some-class">true</class>
                    </additionalClasses>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label>Actions</label>
                    <componentType>actionDelete</componentType>
                </settings>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>

define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'mage/url'
], function ($, _, uiRegistry, select, url) {
    'use strict';

    return select.extend({
        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            const fetchUrl = 'https://local.com/dataflow/index/dynamicattributes';

            // Make the AJAX request
            $.ajax({
                url: fetchUrl,
                showLoader: true,
                data: { form_key: window.FORM_KEY, 'value': value },
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        console.log("AJAX Response: ", response.data);
                        const options = response.data.map(item => ({
                            value: item.value,
                            label: item.label
                        }));

                        // Set options for the template row
                        const dynamicRows = uiRegistry.get('index = dynamic_rows');
                        if (dynamicRows) {
                            const template = dynamicRows.template; // Access the template row
                            if (template) {
                                const field = template.getFormFields('field_1');
                                console.log(field);
                                if (field) {
                                    field.setOptions(options); // Set new options
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.error('Failed to fetch dynamic options:', response.message);
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.error('Error occurred while fetching dynamic options.');
                }
            });
        },
    });
});


In the UI component I have a drop down field. On selection of a value I am sending the AJAX request and I am successfully receiving the response as well.
After receiving the response I have to set the options based on the response data in the UI component's dynamicrows' field_1. I am not sure about the syntax that I have to follow and the changes that I make in the UI Component.
How can I set the options for the field_1 field in dynamicrows ?
